# Range with step in Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

What's the best way to do the following in [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com):

```js
_.range(0, 3, 0);
// => [0, 0, 0]
```

Thank you.

Comment: The answers already show the two ways I would think about handling it.  But if you're interested in *why* Ramda's [`range`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#range) doesn't act that way, you can see [my post on the subject](https://fr.umio.us/ranging-near-and-far/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`R.repeat`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#repeat) to create an array of multiple instances of a single item:

```js
const result = R.repeat(0, 3)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to repeat the same number *n* times, then Ori Drori already provided a good answer with [`repeat`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#repeat).

However if you need to support step, you would have to build a function yourself. (Ramda has a [`range`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#range) function but it does not support step.)

So where Lodash would return:

```
_.range(1, 10, 2);
//=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You can achieve a similar functionality with Ramda [`unfold`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unfold) function:

```
const rangeStep = curry((start, end, step) =>
  unfold(n => n < end ? [n, n + step] : false, start));

rangeStep(1, 10, 2);
//=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```